Powershell hash of hash structure static variable initialization
How to initialize hash of hash structure statically in a powershell script code
tried below, but seems it is not allowed.
$table = @{"a" = @{"x" = 1, "y" = 2, "z" = 3}, "b" = @{"x" = 3, "y" = 4, "z" = 6}}
Got Error as below
PS C:\Users\nkannapp> $table = @{"a"=@{"x" = 1, "y" = 2, "z" = 3}, "b"=@{"x" = 3, "y" = 4, "z" = 6}}
At line:1 char:16
+ $table = @{"a"=@{"x" = 1, "y" = 2, "z" = 3}, "b"=@{"x" = 3, "y" = 4,  ...
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept
assignments, such as a variable or a property.
At line:1 char:46
+ $table = @{"a"=@{"x" = 1, "y" = 2, "z" = 3}, "b"=@{"x" = 3, "y" = 4,  ...
+                                              ~~~
The assignment expression is not valid. The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept
assignments, such as a variable or a property.


you need new line instead of commas, change all commas for semicolons ; and it will work

As Santiago Squarzon points out you'll need a statement terminator - a newline or a semicolon ; - to separate the key value pairs in a hashtable literal instead:
$table = @{
  "a" = @{
    "x" = 1
    "y" = 2
    "z" = 3
  }
  "b" = @{
    "x" = 3
    "y" = 4
    "z" = 6
  }
}
# or 
$table = @{"a" = @{"x" = 1; "y" = 2; "z" = 3}; "b" = @{"x" = 3; "y" = 4; "z" = 6}}


The , is the array operator, so PowerShell interprets the whole line as an array expression that's to be assigned to the x/a key(s):
@{"a"=@{ "x"= 1, "y" = 2, "z" = 3},"b"=@{...},...}
#        \_/  |  \_____/
#         |   |    |
#         |   |   not syntactically valid in array literal expression
#         |  valid numerical expression
#        valid hashtable key as assignment target


@{"a"=@{...},"b"=@{...},...}
# \_/ \____/ \________/
#  |   |       |
#  |   |      not syntactically valid in array literal expression
#  |  valid hashtable literal expression
# valid hashtable key as assignment target

